# Performance of large maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a Clojure program which is using some large maps (1000 - 2000 items) which are accessed 30 - 40 times a second and using Strings as the keys. I was wondering if there is a big performance difference if I used keywords or symbols as the keys instead?

Comment: I bet you could find out more quickly and accurately by trying it out yourself at the REPL than you could by waiting for an answer on SO.

Comment: That's a good idea. How would I do this?

Comment: what will you do, if i say: "using symbols is performance boost", you put such code in production and suffer degradation? will you accuse me? :)
please try it yourself, it's easy - several lines of code

Comment: Is there a version which is "few" lines of code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Clojure map lookups are very fast, and do not particularly depend on the size of the map.

In fact, they are almost as fast as pure Java HashMaps, while enjoying many advantages over traditional HashMaps including being immutable and thread-safe.

If you are only doing 30-40 lookups a second then I guarantee **you will never notice the difference regardless of what you use as keys**. Worrying about this would count as premature optimisation.

Let's prove it: the following code does a million map lookups using strings as keys:

```
(def str-keys (map str (range 1000)))
(def m (zipmap str-keys (range 1000)))
(time (dotimes [i 1000] (doseq [k str-keys] (m k))))
=> "Elapsed time: 69.082224 msecs"
```

The following does a million map lookups using keywords as keys:

```
(def kw-keys (map #(keyword (str %)) (range 1000)))
(def m (zipmap kw-keys (range 1000)))
(time (dotimes [i 1000] (doseq [k kw-keys] (m k))))
=> "Elapsed time: 59.212864 msecs"
```

And for symbols:

```
(def sym-keys (map #(symbol (str %)) (range 1000)))
(def m (zipmap sym-keys (range 1000)))
(time (dotimes [i 1000] (doseq [k sym-keys] (m k))))
=> "Elapsed time: 61.590925 msecs"
```

In my tests, Symbols and Keywords were slightly faster than Strings, but still the difference could easily be explained by statistical error, and the average execution time per lookup was less than 100 *nanoseconds* for all cases.

So your 30-40 lookups are probably taking in the order of 0.001% of your CPU time (this even allows for the fact that in a real app, lookups will probably be a few times slower due to caching issues)

The likely reason for Keywords in particular being slightly faster is that they are interned (and can therefore use reference equality to check for equality). But as you can see the difference is sufficiently small that you really don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Hmm, just for the record I ran these with ClojureScript REPL, got: str-keys:62 msecs, kw-keys:90msec, sym-keys:59 msec.. pretty good IMHO, now, wondering if that's really JavaScript at all.

Comment: Symbols can't use reference equality to test for equality: `((juxt identical? =) 'a 'a) => [false true]`

Comment: @amalloy - haha I assumed that Symbol.intern actually interned the symbol but apparently it doesn't :-) answer edited. But any idea why it doesn't intern them? is this a Clojure implementation bug?

Comment: @mikera: No, it's by design: two copies of "the same" symbol can hold different metadata. However, symbols' *names* are interned, so symbol equality is just a little bit more work than a reference equality test (the strings are extracted -- two per symbol: the namespace and the name --  and then tested for reference equality; well, strictly speaking, "whole Object" reference equality check is attempted first, followed by an `instanceof` check so that a symbol is never equal to a non-symbol; 3x `==`, 1x `instanceof` and 2x field access max to determine that two symbols are equal, if they are).

Comment: Ah got it that makes perfect sense - thanks Michal for the enlightening explanation as always!